# How to calculate the integral of time and speed having db in mongodb and c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, integral

I have a database of a car which is done using MongoDB.
The backend of my application is done using C#.
In my database, I have data about current speed and current time (timestamp).
I need to calculate what is the distance covered since the given date.
The solution would to calculate the integral of speed, but how?

Comment: Could you show sample of your data and expected result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most accurate answer you need to calculate [linear regression](https://gist.github.com/NikolayIT/d86118a3a0cb3f5ed63d674a350d75f2)
representation of the given points which it will give you y= mx +b function
Then you can calculate the integral of any range which will be the distance that you are looking for .
Assuming the speed is changing , if not just the average of the speed will do the trick .